# Database insert/update event listener in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, sybase, sap-iq

I have to implement a database(Sybase) insert/update event listener in spring boot. The challenge is the insert/update of a table in my database is done by an external application or done manually and my spring boot listener should be able to catch this event. Any suggestions on how to proceed ?

Comment: You've tagged this as Sybase IQ is it actually Sybase IQ you're using because functionality varies between the various Sybase (now SAP) database products?

Comment: I'm using interactive sql which most people term it as Sybase IQ. Correct me if I'm wrong here

Comment: No Sybase IQ is SAP's data warehouse product nothing to do with a SQL client - you can use interactive SQL to connect to SAP ASE, IQ or other products. You need to check which underlying SAP database product you're using (e.g. ASE, Anywhere, IQ).